# Pointer type vs result of address of

Tags: c++, pointers

Why does

```
RECT r;
...
GetClientRect(hwnd,&r);
```

work, but

```
LPRECT r =NULL; //must initialize
...
GetClientRect(hwnd,r);
```

does not work?

I think it has to be initialized

Comment: Look at the documentation. For the parameter, it says, "A pointer to a RECT structure that receives the client coordinates." In your second example, `r` points to nothing, not a `RECT` structure.

Comment: @chris but it's the same type. `r` is an out parameter, so it doesnt matter what it points to when `GetClientRect` is called

Comment: Try making the function (with dummy values) and having it work when you pass in a null pointer.

Comment: `strcpy(NULL, "OMG why doesn't this work?!!?!!oneone");` wouldn't work either...

Comment: @Nromaai There is absolutely no way `GetClientRect` or any other function that takes a pointer could make your NULL pointer not a NULL pointer on return.  That's why you need to provide the address of an *existing* RECT so that `GetClientRect` can copy the results to it.

Comment: @JonathanPotter That didn't really add any information

Comment: @Nromaai Just thought I would preempt in case you were planning to ask the same question about every function in existence that requires a pointer to a buffer.

Comment: Without a definition of "work" this question is entirely useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to initialize anything, but you do have provide a pointer to an existing `RECT` struct.  That's where [`GetClientRect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will store the returned client rectangle coordinates. Your `LPRECT` pointer is the right type, but it doesn't point to anything.  If you really want to use a pointer variable, this should work:

```
RECT r;
LPRECT rp = &r;
GetClientRect(hwnd, rp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply the general case to your question.  It doesn't matter if we're talking about a `RECT *`, an `int *`, or a `Widget *`.

The bottom line is that there is absolutely no way you can pass an uninitialized pointer to a function, and have that function initialize the pointer for you.  It is an impossibility in C++.

Take a simple case of passing an `int*` and attempt to change the pointer to point to an `int` on return:

```
void foo(int *x)
{
  // put some code here to attempt to initialize the passed-in pointer
}

int main()
{
   int *p = 0;
   foo(p);  // can you make foo turn p into a non-NULL pointer?  You can't.
}
```

No matter how hard you will try, there is no code in `foo` that you can write that will change the `int*` value passed from `main`.  It can't be done due to the fact that the pointer is passed by value, and passing by value creates a temporary that is destroyed on return of the function.

To actually change the value of a pointer, you either pass a reference to the pointer, or a pointer to the pointer.  However, the function signature has to change to take an `int **` or `int *&`

So to be clear, a function that requires a pointer to `T` *must* be given a pointer to `T` that points somewhere valid (with the exception being pointers set to NULL as indicators to the function that the pointer is not to be used).